# Setting up relationship in the code, after both parent and child are inserted with Core Data?

Tags: core-data, swift

I have an app that uses core data with two entities: `System` and `Owner`. Each `System` has one `Owner` and each `Owner` can 'own' many `System` objects. Both objects are gathered from a remote `JSON` feed independently of each other. I `GET` all the `Owner` objects and load them to disk with Core Data, then I `GET` all the `System` objects and load *those* to disk using Core Data.

Something like this:

```
Owner.createInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext!, ownerID: reducedID, fName: fName, lName: lName)
```

and similarily for the `System` objects.

My `Owner` class looks like this (auto-generated)

```
class Owner: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var firstName: String
    @NSManaged var lastName: String
    @NSManaged var id: String


    class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, ownerID: String, fName: String, lName: String) -> Owner {
        let newOwner = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Owner", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as Owner
        newOwner.id = ownerID
        newOwner.firstName = fName
        newOwner.lastName = lName

        moc.save(nil)
        return newOwner
    }

}
```

and the `System` object looks like this (partially auto-generated):

```
class System: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var cid: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var addy: String
    @NSManaged var rn: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var rnGroup: String
    @NSManaged var lng: String
    @NSManaged var lat: String
    @NSManaged var owner: Owner
    @NSManaged var state: NSNumber


    class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, sysCID: String, sysName: String, sysAddy: String, sysRN: Int, sysRNGroup: String, sysLat: String, sysLng: String) -> System {
  // more code...
```

I can't create these objects concurrently because the `Owner` JSON feed may not be available at the same time as the `System` JSON feed.

My question is, how to I set this `System`<-`Owner` relationship using code *after* all objects are stored to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could not be more intuitive:

```
system.owner = owner;
```

where the first `owner` is the relationship name and the second one the retrieved owner object.

BTW: Looking at your model files, it seems you forgot the inverse relationship from owner to system. Maybe you generated the managed object subclass before finishing your model design.

Also, I recommend using a different name for the `id` attribute - I think "id" is a reserved word and this could lead to terrible errors.

If you need to fetch the owner first, do so with a predicate, e.g. based on `id` (which I will call `ownerID`), do something like

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Owner")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"ownerID = %@", ownerIDString)
let result = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error:nil)! as [Owner]
if countElements(result) == 1 {
   let owner = result[0]!
   system.owner = owner
}
```

Comment: Well, I understand that it's as simple as `system.owner=owner` but I guess my question is more about retrieving that second `owner`. Do I do a `fetchRequest` then assign that result to the `system.owner`? Something like `fetchRequest = *insert code* as? Owner` and then assign to `system.owner`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Fetch the `owner` (with a predicate describing the unique attribute, like a name or id) and assign to system as show above.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and code example (which was close to what I had, but not quite hence my confusion). And you're right about my choice of `id` as an attribute name. Bad form!